# How to load requested file from sub-directory without rewriting base

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite, apache2

Utilizing `.htaccess` rules, I'm attempting to load a file from within a sub-directory while keeping the frontend URL unchanged if both the domain and file path match criteria.

**Example of URL:**

```
example.com/specificfile.xml
```

**The file itself is within a sub-directory that is not the public web root:**

```
/var/www/feeds/specificfile.xml
```

While attempting to Google this, I'm getting a lot of results for `RewriteBase` but that's not what I'm after. I need to "rewrite base directory" for only a single file and retain the frontend URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `/var/www` is the document root then in order to serve `/feeds/specificfile.xml` when requesting `/specificfile.xml` you would do the following using mod_rewrite in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^specificfile\.xml$ feeds/$0 [L]
```

For this to work, `RewriteBase` must either be not set at all (preferable) or set to `RewriteBase /`.

The `$0` backreference simply saves repetition - it refers to the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. `specificfile.xml`.

Note that if you have existing mod_rewrite directives in your `.htaccess` file then *order matters*. (eg. External/canonical redirects need to go first.)